# How to find the data-type based on the button clicked using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a PHP function that creates dynamic created division. Each of these divisions have a different data-type and a button. How do I retrieve the data-type of a division when the user clicks on the submit button using Javascript?

**PHP CODE:**

```
function html_submit_docs($docname,$datasubmit){

$html .= '<section class="docs">';
    $html .= 
    '<div class="card_doc">
        <div class="custome-file" data-type="'.$datasubmit.'">
          <div id="label">
            Upload Your Document
          </div>
          <input type="file" />
          <button id="upload" value="Upload" />
        </div>
    </div>';
  $html .= '</section>';
    return $html;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE:**

```
$(document).on('click', '#upload', function() {
console.log('button activattion');
var form_data = new FormData();
var doctype = $(this).closest('div').find('data-type').attr('data-type');
console.log(doctype);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxobject.ajaxurl,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: {
            action: 'upload_submit_docs',
            testuser: ajaxobject.student_id,
            doctype: doctype,
            form_data: form_data

        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log('err', err)}
    });

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery you can use `data()`:

```
var doctype = $(this).closest('div').data('type');
```

Comment: Will this catch value of the $datasubmit inside data-type="'.$datasubmit.'?

Comment: Assuming that your HTML renders correctly, yes it will catch the value.